# Firebase Cloud Functions Call : error : Object message : "Bad Request" status : "INVALID_ARGUMENT"

Tags: react-native, google-cloud-functions

first of all i am working with react-native

i wanted to use Custom Claims on my project since it seems to fit the role distribution i expect to use on my app.

after setting my app following the documentation i succeed on creating some functions

but, here's the thing, when i try to call a function by fetching the endpoint i always get this error :

**in the console**

> error
>   :
>   Object
>   message
>   :
>   "Bad Request"
>   status
>   :
>   "INVALID_ARGUMENT"

**in firebase console**

> ```
>    addAdminRoleTest    Request body is missing data. { email: 'dev@test.com' }
> ```

i couldn't find any answer to that except that i send wrong information from my fetch but i don't understand why.

i even tried to simplify my function only to get the data i sent but i had the exact same error

find below my cloud function & the calling method :

**functions/index.js**

```
exports.addAdminRole = functions.https.onCall((data, context) => {
    // get user
    return admin.auth().getUserByEmail(data.email).then(user => {
        // if not already (admin)
        if(user.customClaims && (user.customClaims).admin === true) {
            return;
        }
        // add custom claim (admin)
        return admin.auth().setCustomUserClaims(user.uid, {
            admin: true
        });
    }).then(() => {
        return {
            message: `Bravo : ${data.email} fait partie de l'équipe Admins`
        }
    }).catch(err => {
        return err;
    });
});
```

**simplified function :**

```
exports.addAdminRoleTest = functions.https.onCall(data => {
    console.log("parse data : "+JSON.parse(data));
    return (
        JSON.parse(data)
    );
});
```

**adminScreen.js**

```
function httpAddAdminRole() {

    const initRequest = {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
            Accept: 'application/json',
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        },
        body:JSON.stringify({
            email: 'dev@test.com'
        })
    }

    console.log(initRequest);

    return fetch('https://us-central1-my-project.cloudfunctions.net/addAdminRole', initRequest)
      .catch(err => console.log(err))
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(parsedRes => {
          console.log(parsedRes);
      });
}
```

Answer (score 6):

in the end this was mostly json knowledge that missed me

my **body** should have **data** included

here's the answer i came to :

**functions/index.js**

```
exports.addAdminRole = functions.https.onCall((data, context) => {
    const dataParsed = JSON.parse(data);

    // get user
    return admin.auth().getUserByEmail(dataParsed.email).then(user => {
        // if not already (admin)
        if(user.customClaims && (user.customClaims).admin === true) {
            console.log(dataParsed.email + " is already an Admin");
            return;
        }
        // add custom claim (admin)
        return admin.auth().setCustomUserClaims(user.uid, {
            admin: true
        });
    }).then(() => {
        return {
            message: `Bravo : ${dataParsed.email} is now an Admin`
        }
    }).catch(err => {
        return err;
    });
});
```

**adminScreen.js**

```
function httpAddAdminRole(mail) {

    const initRequest = {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
            Accept: 'application/json',
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        },
        body:JSON.stringify({ 
            data:JSON.stringify({
                email: mail
            })
        })
    }

    console.log(initRequest);

    return fetch('https://us-central1-my-project.cloudfunctions.net/addAdminRole', initRequest)
      .catch(err => console.log(err))
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(parsedRes => {
          console.log(parsedRes);
      });
}
```